# Second ethernet card for ubuntu server

Tags: networking, ssh, pcie

I have a working ethernet port on my motherboard that connects to the internet in the network. However, due to the size of the network the connection tends to be rather slow. It's not a good thing if even your terminal via ssh needs several seconds to show what you just typed. Hence, I would like to add a second ethernet port for a computer-to-computer connection via a pci card. Is this possible? Is there anything special I need to pay attention to concerning the type of card or software problems?

I read in another thread that I might need a crossover cable to make it work.

Thank you very much!
Seb

Comment: Nowadays it's very likely that you [dont't need a crossover cable](https://serverfault.com/q/579951/346811). Modern NICs automatically swap the lines internally.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any other ideas about restrictions?